# Fixed Size Image Placeholder White Space

Tags: html, image, height, width, whitespace

I just want to know how I can insert white space onto an HTML page with a fixed size. For example something like this:

```
<div width="48" height="48"></div>
```

But that doesn't work. So I tried adding an image tag without a source like this:

```
<img width="48" height="48">
```

That worked but there was a 48x48 square with nothing inside it as there is no image source. I tried using CSS to change border to 0 pixels and setting it's colour to white but it doesn't work and the square stays.

Then I tried using break tags but the problem with them is I can't have an exact 48x48 empty white space.

How does one go about inserting a fixed size white space in their page?

And if you're wondering why I want to add a white space. It's because in that white space a little image appears later on and when it does, all the stuff that was there moves down to make space for the image but I don't want things moving around like that. So I want to insert a white space the same size as my image and then replace the space with an image.

Im going to be putting the space in a div and then using .innerHTML to change the code in-between the div tags to replace the space with an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use service called Placehold.it

`<img src="http://placehold.it/500x200" />`

or write custom CSS for it..

```
.virtualPlaceholder {
    display:block;
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    background:#eee;
}
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/7Ufn6/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm not very good with CSS at the moment but I have been learning very fast in HTML and JavaScript. I used your method and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS style `white-space: pre;`

You can actually add white-spaces inside to your code and make them apply on your page.
So you can add as many white-spaces as you want untill you get the desired length.

Example(html):

```
<h2 class="addWhiteSpace">
                A                    B the white-space between A and B will be applied in the page.
            </h2>
```

CSS:

```
.addWhiteSpace{
    white-space: pre;
}
```